# MSVC C4100: 'application' : unreferenced formal parameter warning

Tags: qt, visual-c++, warnings

The following code generates a C4100 warning when compiling using MSVC. How is this possible? "appliation" is clearly being referenced.

```
class ApplicationInfo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ...
        static void initialize(QApplication &application);
        ...
    ...
}

void ApplicationInfo::initialize(QApplication &application)
{
    application.setOrganizationName(ApplicationInfo::organizationName());
    application.setOrganizationDomain(ApplicationInfo::organizationName());
    application.setApplicationName(ApplicationInfo::applicationName());
    application.setApplicationVersion(ApplicationInfo::applicationVersion().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions you are calling using the `application` object are static functions, so they aren't really referencing the `application` object.

```
setOrganizationName
setOrganizationDomain
setApplicationName
setApplicationVersion
```

Are all static members of `QCoreApplication` which `QApplication` derives from. Using the `application` reference only resolves the name scoping for these functions, but the object isn't actually used.